# How does Google obtain my IP address (in contrast with whatismyip.com)?

Tags: networking, mobile, ip, ip-address

When searching for "what is my ip" from a mobile device not connected to WiFi, Google and whatismyip.com sometimes return different results. Our servers can only see the IP returned by whatismyip.com by checking getRemoteAddr() and X-Forwarded-For.

We're unable to see the IP address returned by Google. How can we see the IP address Google sees?

[image: Google IP result]
[image: WhatIsMyIP result]

Comment: you're hitting different sites. it stands to reason that your ISP has different external gateways to handle each of their own upstream providers. you just happen to be going out two different gateways - one that's "closer" to google, and one that's "closer" to whatismyip.

Comment: How come this doesn't happen when I'm connected to a regular wireless network but happens when I'm on a mobile data network? (AT&T LTE, NYC)

Comment: because it's a totally different network/provider. So probably AT&T chose to have multiple different NAT gateways, and whoever your "wireless network" (wifi?) provider is has fewer gateways.